# How to get a 3D navigation view in Bing maps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am relatively new to Bing Maps. I wanted to know if there is any way to achieve a 3D navigation view somewhat like in Here Drive+ because by default we have the bird's eye view or I can say the perpendicular view. ..[image: I what the map view to look somewhat like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try the pitch argument in the 
TrySetViewAsync(Geopoint, zoomLevel(Double), Heading(Double), DesiredPitch(Double), MapAnimationKind) method. For more information follow [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn637062.aspx). Your code would look somewhat like this:
 `await MyMap.TrySetViewAsync(mypoint, 15, 0, 70, MapAnimationKind.Bow);`